# AWS DynamoDB Cloudformation template validation failing - "not encrypted", - but it is

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cdk

I've made a DynamoDB table ("UserActivityXXXX") using AWS CDK using AWS Managed encryption.
The template for it is shown below, and the property SSESpecification.SSEEnable is set to true. However, when running template validation, it fails, daysing the the ddb table isn't encrypted and that i should add that property (screenshot below).

Can anyone help me sort this out. Thanks!!

CDK Code

```
    const userActivityTable = new dynamodb.Table(this, "UserActivityTable", {
        encryption: dynamodb.TableEncryption.AWS_MANAGED,
        partitionKey: {name: "userid", type: dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING}
    })
```

Template

```
  UserActivityTableXXXX:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: userid
          KeyType: HASH
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: userid
          AttributeType: S
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: 5
        WriteCapacityUnits: 5
      SSESpecification:
        SSEEnabled: true
```

Error

```
| Resources: 
| 
| ► Failing in ressource: UserActivityTableXXXX, with Type: COMPLIANCE, Severity: 3
| Name: dynamodb-encryption-check
| Description: DynamoDB table is not encrypted.
| How-to fix: Use attribute SSEEnabled=true. 
| 
| 
|
| DynamoDB Table is not compliant
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I've removed the pics, any help with the question would be appreciated

Comment: What kind of validation is this? cfn-nag?

Comment: Yes, that's right, cfn-nag (sorry i was trying to work out what it was for a while)

Comment: Then you must be using a custom rule, because that's not what the one that ships with cfn-nag outputs: https://github.com/stelligent/cfn_nag/blob/master/lib/cfn-nag/custom_rules/DynamoDBEncryptionRule.rb

Comment: Okay thanks! I'm not certain where I find that but I'll take a look at what rules we're using!

Answer (score 0):

Which ruling mechanism are you using, AWS Config? If so, then you must state the KMS ARN in the `kmsKeyArns` input parameter for the rule to be compliant.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/dynamodb-table-encrypted-kms.html

Comment: They said it's `cfn-nag` in the comments.